# Test character set ISO 20022

Tags: xml, regex

For a banking program in Excel, I am looking for a way to test (validate) the characters in a message.

I use Regular Expressions for validation of an e-mail address. Now I'm looking for a similar way to test if the used characters are correct.

According to the XML standard they should be `a-z A-Z 0-9 and /-?:()-,'+`. The numbers and digits are easy enough, but what about testing the special symbols?

Regards,
Ronald

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What are you using to validate your XML? Just schema? You can use a regex for that too (just escape special characters like `?` with `\?`). See [this](http://www.xmlschemareference.com/regularExpression.html) for reference.

Comment: I really recommend to read this [checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) before asking a question...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I read the checklist, I looked through the FAQ and earlier questions but couldn't find what I was looking for. As I wrote: I used the RegExp tot validate an email address (also found on this forum) but couldn't figure out what string to use to validate normal text. Down here are some examples which I'm going to try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\:\(\)\'\+]+$
```

Just needed to escape the **special characters** (`?\()`)

will match with `'(asd098/-:)'+` for example.

**Explanation:**

- `^` Delimiter indicating begin of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\:\(\)\'\+]+` Match `a~z`, `A~Z`, `/`, `-`, `:`, `(`, `)`, `'`, `+` one or more times.
- `$` Delitmiter indicating end of string

Comment: I just added a few other characters (?., and space) and it worked! This is the string I was looking or. Still don't understand it completely bu I will study that. Thanks!

Comment: See the edition, I just added an explanation, perhaps it helps.

Comment: The backslashes are unnecessary inside a character class. That is, you are including backslash among the allowed characters, multiple times.

Comment: Times ago I thought it was necessary, but recently, someone explained me the same thing you said, and yes **I agree with you**, but backslash is **not a problem** escaping "allowed characters" inside a character class, so I think is much more easy use this way as a "good practice". You can disagree, but is not wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just put them in a character class:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\/?:(),'+-]+
```

`+` means one or more sequences of those letters

Answer (score 0):

You may test for:

```
[^a-zA-Z\d/\-?:(),' +]
```

Any match will represent an invalid character.